# How to load SQLite data into a viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, fragmentpageradapter

I am new to android programming and I need to load each rows from an SQLite database into a viewpager (My SQLite database contains fields "ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS"), so that I can be able to navigate to each row by swiping left and right. I am unsuccessful in finding the right solution to this. I have been trying to solve this problem for a week now.

It would be a blessing if someone can help me out with this. Thank you very much!

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: I am able to navigate through SQLite records using the left and right swipe gestures and having each field loaded into textviews. I can load each record using cursor.movetonext, cursor.movetoprevious, etc.I have seen applications that use the viewpager method which adds great animation in navigating through pages, but I am in no luck getting close to even loading SQLite data into viewpages as I am unsure how. Hope you can help me.

Comment: I was able to play around with some codes in using viewpager and I am able to create a viewpager example, but many examples out there only shows it with a fixed number of pages. I need to set the number of pages and the data from each page based on the data in my SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tons of research and tries, I was able to come up with a working solution. The code below is all listed in the MainActivity. Pretty straight forward. I hope this helps out other people out there. Leave a comment if you have any questions.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

float x1,x2;
float y1, y2;

int currentPage;
ViewPager mViewPager;
String ID;
List<String> listID = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> listMtrno = new ArrayList<String>();
String SearchString = null;
CursorPagerAdapter mAdapter;
Cursor cursor;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.pager);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
    cursor = databaseHelper.fetch();
    mAdapter = new CursorPagerAdapter(this, cursor);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

    if (extras != null)
    {
        SearchString = extras.getString("SearchFlag");
        if (SearchString != null) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(SearchString) - 1);

        } else {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Search(A): " + SearchString);
    }
}

private class CursorPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Cursor cursor;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CursorPagerAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        Log.d("Main Activity", "MyCursorPagerAdapter.onCreate()");

        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        //if(cursor != null) {

        Log.d("Main Activity", "swapCursor().");

        this.cursor = cursor;
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
        //}
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(cursor == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup view, int position, Object object) {

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        (view).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {

        position = position % cursor.getCount();

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listener, null);

        TextView f1_recno = layout.findViewById(R.id.TV_recno);
        TextView f1_acctno = layout.findViewById(R.id.TV_acctno);
        TextView f1_route = layout.findViewById(R.id.TV_route);
        TextView fl_name = layout.findViewById(R.id.TV_name);
        TextView fl_mtrno = layout.findViewById(R.id.TV_mtrno);

        f1_recno.setText((cursor.getPosition() + 1) + " of " + cursor.getCount() + " records");
        f1_acctno.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ACCTNO")));
        f1_route.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ROUTE")));
        fl_name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME")));
        fl_mtrno.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MTRNO")));

            (view).addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

I load a table from a database to a cursor object, and connect it to my CursorPagerAdapter. The loading of each row data is done in the InstantiateItem object.